# Stored procedures not working (System.TypeInitializationException)

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I keep getting this error and I don't know how to fix it.

An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in WebApplication1.dll but was not handled in user code

Apparently it doesn't matter if I use an existing or not existing stored procedure, I'll get the error anyway.

In my config I have a connectionstring like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="data source=PC\SQLEXPRESS;database=db;uid=dbuser;pwd=E1485517-5C5B-4D85-AFD3-0A4C4522F8BD" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and over here I want to use the stored procedure:

```
public static Student GetStudentById(int studentid)
{
    DbCommand dbCommand = DB.GetSqlStringCommand("GetStudentById");
    dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    DB.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@id", DbType.Int32, studentid);

    using (IDataReader dr = DB.ExecuteReader(dbCommand))
    {
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            return new Student
            {
                fullname = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("fullname"))
            };
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Any clue what I'm missing?

It's this line: 
`DbCommand dbCommand = DB.GetSqlStringCommand("GetStudentById");` The exception message is in Dutch, translated it would be: "The type initialization function for BaseDAL has caused an exception". 
My BaseDAL looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data; 

public class BaseDAL 
{ 
  public static Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database DB = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("db"); 
}
```

EDIT: I just found the problem, the login failed for the user, that's why it didn't work.

Comment: Which line does the exception get thrown on?

Comment: You're missing the exception message.

Comment: Is this function being part of a class being constructed?

Comment: wrap the usage of `DbCommand` inside a `using` block.

Comment: In case you missed my comment: the _type_ of an exception usually doesn't tell you much. You need to inspect (and update your question with) the exception message.

Comment: It's this line:
"DbCommand dbCommand = DB.GetSqlStringCommand("GetStudentById");"

The exception message is in Dutch, translated it would be:
"The type initialization function for BaseDAL has caused an exception".

My BaseDAL looks like this:

using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;

public class BaseDAL
{
    public static Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database DB = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("db");
}

Comment: Then check the InnerException... There is an underlying issue that will tell you exactly what's wrong. We can't analyze this from the information given. You can always try http://unlocalize.com/.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

go to Application pool -> Advanced Settings  and set the `Identity` of `Process Model` to `Local System`.

[image]

Comment: What? Why would you do this?

Comment: I had the same login failure issue couple of weeks back when I was trying to access the localdb from IIS. This change worked for me.

Comment: That's voodoo programming. You don't know what this change does, but it works, so you keep applying it. The LocalSystem account is a semi-administrator account which you **should never want to use** as application pool identity, as it exposes your entire system using your web application as a remote control panel for hackers. Do not make such harmful suggestions to others if you don't understand their problem. You can use comments to ask OP to verify your suspicions; don't post guesses as answers.

Comment: I never had an idea about these potential harm even in my case. I'll be careful around security.Thanks for leading.

Comment: The OP said about login failure, which was for me too. But identity is more important that I ever thought.